# how to call interstitial 2nd time

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I want to show interstitial in same activity more than one time. I am using below method for interstitial but it show interstitial only one time and never reloaded.

```
  int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 /// so on};
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // for interstitial
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd ( this ); 
     interstitial.setAdUnitId (my ad id);
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder=new AdRequest.Builder ();

    interstitial.setAdListener ( new AdListener (){
    }
    });
   interstitial.loadAd ( adRequestBuilder.Build ());

        hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
         iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext); 
         gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrev); 
       //Just set one Click listener for the image 
        iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener); 
         gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener); 
        }
         View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(View v) {
        //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
          currentImage++;
         currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
       hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 

         / / here to show interstitial
          if (interstitial. isLoaded ()){
              interstitial.show ();
           }
         } }; 
        View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(View v) { 
         //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
           currentImage--; 
            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length; 
           hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
           } 
           };
```

As I pressed button then interstitial shows. I want to show interstitial as some images viewed. For example after 10th and 20th and so on or after 5 minutes etc. Kindly help me how can I recall interstitial and show it after some images. Kindly help me with code or edit my code. I have completely no idea how can I achieve this task. I'll be very thankfull.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify your adlistener code to

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


 @Override
      public void onAdLoaded() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(timestamp > lastTimeAdFail + 120*1000)
            {
              AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

                // Load the interstitial ad again
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            }

      }

      @Override
      public void onAdClosed () 
      {
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

            // Load the interstitial ad again
          interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
      }
    });
```

Also modify your onclick listener to

```
View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(View v) {
        //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
          currentImage++;
         currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
       hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
 if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                if(timestamp > lastTimeAdShown + 300*1000)
                                {
                                    interstitial.show();

                                    lastTimeAdShown = timestamp;
                                }

                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if(timestamp > lastTimeAdFail + 120*1000)
                                {
                                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

                                    // Load the interstitial ad.
                                    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

                                    lastTimeAdFail = timestamp;
                                }
                            }

         } };
```

EDIT: Define two class variables as

```
private long lastTimeAdShown=System.currentTimeMillis();

private long lastTimeAdFail=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Very very thanx to reply. lastTimeAdFail &  lastTimeAdShown both shows error. Waiting your reply.

Comment: thanks, i edited the code to add 2 variables as class variables. please try now

Comment: If you want to show ads instantly at the first time, you can set both these variables to 0

Comment: I have no words to say thank you. Thanx very very very much. Love u man.

Comment: Good one, i'll be using it! The adRequest can be a member variable for cleaner code.